# How to configure SRX200 router?

Tags: configuration, router, lan, trusted

How to configure SRX200 router?
I want to setup a LAN (trusted network) with my own series (ex: 10.x.x.x)
Router should forward the request based on port(Port based forwarding).
i.e If any machine sent a request on a port, router should forward the request to a specific machine based on that port number. Router should translate the destination address to one specific IP (specified by us).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could configure the juniper router in two ways. 
1. Through cli prompt
2. Web interface

To Configure router with web interface, find the complete information from the following link.
http://forums.juniper.net/jnet/attachments/jnet/Learning/47/

The above document provides complete information.
You can configure the port based redirection using Destination NAT and IP based redirection with Static NAT.